# a specific function applied over a finite sequence of natural numbers

Tags: summation

First, i'm not a mathematician, and also English is not my first language, so if this question is a duplicate or an equivalent of an existing one - its due to my unsuccessful searching attempts. I have no excuse, it's totally my own fault, and I am sincerely sorry for that.

Anyway, the problem goes like this:
Assuming we have a sequence $A = (a_1, a_2, ... ,a_n \in N )$.

We define a function of such a sequence:
 $$f(A) = a_{i-1} \cdot a_i \cdot a_{i+1} + f(A\setminus\{a_i\}),~~~ |A| >2, i \in \{2, 3, ... , n-1\}$$
$$ f(A) = 0, ~~ |A| <=2$$
($f(A)$ is the product of three adjacent elements plus $f(A')$ where $A'$ is $A$ excluding the middle element of a triplet. There is finite, though very large number of ways to choose the triplet at each step. The recursion ends, when the sequence has only two elements left.)

Now, I need to prove, or disprove, or find a counter-example to this statement:
The smallest possible result of $f(A)$ is produced, if at every iteration $i$ is chosen in such a way that $a_i$  is the maximum element of A.

I'm kinda stuck, so I would be very grateful even for a direction to move in, though a detailed explanation would of course be welcome.

(NB: This is not a homework or something like that, just a thing I encountered and was curious about. It's haunting me.)

Comment: Your function $f(A)$ is not well defined, since (as you note) there may be multiple ways to choose $i$. That seems intentional on your part, but you may want to make that more clear. Perhaps make $f(A)$ also dependent on a permutation of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.

Comment: A couple notational issues:  your $A$ is a sequence, not a set, because you care what order the elements are in.  Your $f(A)$ is not a function because it can have various results depending on the order you choose the $i$'s in.  It is probably most useful to consider it a function from sequences of middle elements to the value you are computing.  You are asking to show that one particular sequence of middle elements maximizes this function.

Comment: I'm really sorry guys, I am ashamed. What would be the correct notation?

Comment: Generally sequences are placed in parentheses, not braces.  I think it comes from an analogy with ordered pairs.  Then your $f(A)$ should be $\min_i a_{i-1}a_ia_{i+1}+f(A')$.  I don't know how we show a sequence with one member deleted (as a replacement for your set minus).  No need t be sorry-most of us are still learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with a small case.  The smallest sequence $A$ that this makes sense for is four elements.  In that case you only have one choice to make, so there are only two possible results.  Let your starting sequence be $(a,b,c,d)$ and write out the results of choosing each of $b$ and $c$.  If $b \gt c$, does it force that the result choosing $b$ is less than the result choosing $c$?  You should be able to find a counterexample.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was able to find my counter-example using your advice! Given $(a, b, c, d)$ and $ b> c$ I was able to find $a$ and $d$ such as $a \cdot b \cdot c + a \cdot c \cdot d > b \cdot c \cdot d + a \cdot b \cdot d$